# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException only for MD_LIFETAB_P9516

Tags: java, android

In my analytics tool, I can see that there is a noticeable amount of crashes with the MD_LIFETAB_P9516 (Medion Lifetab). They are crashing with the stacktrace given below.

It doesn't happen with any other device, though. In the analytics, I can see that in all cases there was enough free disk space. My DatabaseHelper is nothing special. There is an onCreate() with a few execSQL statements, an empty onUpgrade() and truncateAll() crashes at the following line:

```
    SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
```

Stacktrace:

```
0   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unable to open database file
1   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.dbopen(Native Method)
2   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1013)
3   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:986)
4   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:1051)
5   at android.app.ContextImpl.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextImpl.java:770)
6   at android.content.ContextWrapper.openOrCreateDatabase(ContextWrapper.java:221)
7   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:157)
8   at com.unitedinternet.portal.android.photo.database.DatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase(DatabaseHelper.java:61)
9   at com.unitedinternet.portal.android.photo.database.DatabaseHelper.truncateAll(DatabaseHelper.java:162)
10  at com.unitedinternet.portal.android.photo.activity.LoginActivity.onAuthenticationResult(LoginActivity.java:195)
11  at com.unitedinternet.portal.android.photo.activity.LoginRunnable$1.run(LoginActivity.java:305)
12  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
13  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
14  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
15  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
16  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
17  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
18  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
19  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
20  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any idea, what might be causing the problem? Where would you look into?

Comment: Did you manage to find anything on this? I'm experiencing something similar - ONLY on Android 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

After some more investigation, I found out that crashes are happening quite often after the ICS update. Somehow they managed to destroy the application data for many (all?) apps.

Medion recommends to re-install all broken apps. There seems to be nothing we 3rd-party developers can do about it.

Further read (in german):
http://www.n-droid.de/android-4-0-update-fur-medion-lifetab-probleme-und-losungsansatze-im-uberblick.html

Comment: I experienced the same problem when testing an app in the emulator with ICS (API 15). It was crashing on `getReadableDatabase();` with no logical reason. I had a previous version of the same app, and only after deleting it, it started working. I have not noticed this problem on any other device (real or emulated).