# How to check if the database connection is successful or not in android?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have tried several codes on using database. i am trying to use an existing database which i copy to assets folder. I want my pop up to display the outcome of an sql query. The code i have tried is

```
package com.example.singlepop;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Single extends Activity {
    PopupWindow popUp;
     LinearLayout layout;
     TextView tv;
     LayoutParams params;
     LinearLayout mainLayout;
     Button but;
     boolean click = true;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        DataBaseHelper myDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(this);
         try {

             myDbHelper.createDataBase();

             } catch (IOException ioe) {

             throw new Error("Unable to create database");

             }
         try {

             myDbHelper.openDataBase();

             }catch(SQLException sqle){

             throw sqle;

             }

          popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
          layout = new LinearLayout(this);
          mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);



          final Calendar cld = Calendar.getInstance();

          int time = cld.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
          if(time==20)
          {
              tv = new TextView(this);
              but = new Button(this);

          but.setText("Click me for pop up");
          but.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           public void onClick(View v) {
            if (click) {
             popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
             popUp.update(50, 50, 300, 80);
             click = false;
            } else {
             popUp.dismiss();
             click = true;
            }
           }

          });
          params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
          layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
          //tv.setText("Time is 8 pm");

          // display the outcome of the query
          tv.setText(myDbHelper.thought());


          layout.addView(tv, params);
          popUp.setContentView(layout);
          // popUp.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 10, 10);
          mainLayout.addView(but, params);
          setContentView(mainLayout);
          }
          else
          {
              tv.setText("NO TIME");
          }




    }




    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.single, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

This code gives me successful pop up. I have a database "MyDatabase" created n copied on to assets folder. My DataBaseHelper class is

```
package com.example.singlepop;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
     private static final int _id = 1;

    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.singlepop/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "MyDatabase";

    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

    private final Context myContext;

    private static String DB_TABLE = "Totlist";

    private static final String tot = null;

    String des=tot;

    /**
      * Constructor
      * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
      */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {

    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
    }

     /**
      * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
      * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist){
    //do nothing - database already exist
    }else{

    //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
    //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
    this.getReadableDatabase();

    try {

    copyDataBase();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    throw new Error("Error copying database");


    }

    }
    }   

     /**
      * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
      * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
      */
    private boolean checkDataBase(){

    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try{
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){

    //database does't exist yet.

    }

    if(checkDB != null){

    checkDB.close();

    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }

     /**
      * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
      * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
      * This is done by transfering bytestream.
      * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
    myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }

    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();

    }

     public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

        }

     @Override
     public synchronized void close() {

     if(myDataBase != null)
     myDataBase.close();

     super.close();

     }

     @Override
     public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

     }

         // This function should return the outcome of the query but below code is wrong
     public String thought()
     {

         String quer="Hello";
         String sql = "SELECT * FROM option WHERE id = 1";
         Cursor check = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
         quer=String.valueOf(check);
        return quer;

     }



}
```

`rawQuery` returns a `Cursor` type which i am not able display using setText. what should I do so that I can get the outcome of the query to b displayed in the pop up. 
when i run this i get many errors in `logcat`. it could be problem with connectivity.

```
08-28 20:00:57.396: E/Trace(841): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-28 20:00:59.003: E/SQLiteLog(841): (14) cannot open file at line 30176 of [00bb9c9ce4]
08-28 20:00:59.023: E/SQLiteLog(841): (14) os_unix.c:30176: (2) open(/data/data/com.example.singlepop/databases/MyDatabase) - 
08-28 20:00:59.173: E/SQLiteDatabase(841): Failed to open database '/data/data/com.example.singlepop/databases/MyDatabase'.
08-28 20:00:59.173: E/SQLiteDatabase(841): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
```

still a lot of errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error messages you get indicate that a database file `/data/data/com.example.singlepop/databases/MyDatabase` does not exist. Can you check that?

Also, once this works, the `Cursor` represents all the results you get from the query. More than one record can be returned. You first position the cursor to the row you want to read and then you have access to the individual columns. For example (leaving out all error handling and assuming that your table has a column named `col1`):

```
check.moveToFirst();
String col1 = check.getString(check.getColumnIndex("col1"));
```

Comment: i went into the workspace and followed the path. i only find the 2 .java files but no MyDatabase. does that mean the connection is not established??

Comment: what should i use if i have more than 1 column to return?

Comment: repeat the last line for the other columns.

Comment: but how can i return more than 1 string at a time in a function or method? I have a query which gives me all columns of a particular row. But with ur code i can only return one string. but i need 4 strings to be returned.

Comment: Define a class that represents the columns of one row, create an instance and put the different values in. Then return the instance.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to test the database connectivity by sending some trivial SQL like

```
 select 1;
```

This should return exactly 1 and nothing else, and it will definitely fail when there is no connection to the database. Such query does not assume rights to create or access any tables, does not modify anything and works independently from the actual database content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but here's how you would setup and read from a database:

```
public class SQLTest extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "TestDatabase.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private Context context;

public static final String TABLENAME = "mytable";
public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
public static final String COL_NAME = "name";


public SQLSimple(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String STATEMENT_CREATE = "create table if not exists '"+TABLENAME+"' ("
        +COL_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "
        +COL_NAME+" text not null, "
    db.execSQL(STATEMENT_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    String STATEMENT_DROP = "drop table if exists '"+TABLENAME+"';";
    db.execSQL(STATEMENT_DROP);

    onCreate(db);
}

public String readName(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        //Return these two columns only. Here, we only have two of course, but in a bigger table this is good for performance.
        String[] projection = new String[]{COL_ID, COL_NAME};

        //The where part of the query that defines what we are looking for
        String selection = COL_ID + " = ?";

        //The data that will replace the ? in the query before. Doing it this way is to prevent injection and escaping errors
        String selectionArgs[] = new String[]{id+""};
        cursor = db.query(TABLENAME, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

        String name = null;

        if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME));
        }

        return name;
    } finally {
        //Close the database before returning item, even in the case of an exception
        if (cursor != null && !cursor.isClosed()) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        if (db.isOpen()) {
            db.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that this answers your question. If not, please ask.

Comment: i have a database with 2 fields, id and description. i have created this database using sqlite browser. my app should display the content in the field "description" of my database. I have specified the location where it should be displayed in my code

Comment: my app has to display a pop everyday in the morning. the popup should be the content in the description field of my database. thats all i need

Comment: Oh ok. Well, first you need to know that the app expects the database to be in /data/data/<yourpackage>/database/YourDatabase.db. You'll have to try if it works from a different folder, I'm not sure about that. So let's assume you've put it in the right place, then take exactly my code, but leave the onCreate and onUpgrade empty, change the database and table names, modify the column names accordingly and then you can use readName(id) to get your description (You should rename that method as well, of course). Hope that helps!

Comment: i am trying out your code but it asks me to create TreeElementsContract method. i have no idea what this TreeElementsContract should contain

Comment: I'm sorry, that's a fragment from my real code. I edited it out in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your database file is in assets folder. And you are calling `createDataBase()` in which you first check for existence of database using `checkDataBase()`.And then you are calling `copyDataBase()`;

So when you try to open the database at `/data/data/com.example.singlepop/databases/MyDatabase`.
in `checkDataBase()` you get that exception because the database is still in the /assets folder until you call  copyDatabase()

ie.

1. `error opening trace file: No such file or directory`
2. `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database`

**You must first copy the database into the appropriate location before trying to open it.**

I would suggest you to use [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) recommended by  CommonsWare himself.